# Match string after second occurrence of '/'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do the following:

Let's say we have an iterator returning strings looking like this:

```
/*/*/*/*/*/
```

where * can be any string.
I would like a match if the second * is equal to some arbitrary string, lets say 'test'.

```
/*/test/*/*/*/  <--- match
```

Comment: why not use split?

Comment: can you include corner cases in your question? it can be useful to readers to spot the best answer for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need a regex, then you can do it this way:

```
def check(s):
    return re.match(r"\/[^\/]*\/test\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/", s) is None

print(check("/one/test/three/four/five/"))
print(check("/one/two/three/four/five/"))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

This requires that there is exactly the pattern `/*/test/*/*/*/`, where `*` is everything except for `/`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
def check(s, index, searched_match):
    return s.split('/')[index] == searched_match

print(check("/*/test/*/*/*/", 2, "test"))
>>> True
```

You can also use the maxsplit parameter of the `split` method (use it only if you are sure that there is something after `test`) :

```
def check(s, index, searched_match):
    return s.split('/', index + 1)[-2] == searched_match
```

Comment: you could also use maxsplit and then [-1]

Comment: @MikeScotty @imperosol my guess is that `split` won't work because he doesn't know the word he needs to look for, he just knows that there may be letters (or not) in the string that is output by the iterator (he calls it "some arbitrary string" in the question)

Comment: @MikeScotty Added this, thx

Comment: This only matches `/*/test`, not `/*/test/*/*/*/`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tested it. I can assure you the first function works with both test cases.